# How Github repo can use AWS laravel elastic beanstalk environment variables without .env file

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My elastic beanstalk laravel environment variables:

RDS_DB_NAME  - aws.dfsefsd.us-east-1.com

RDS_HOSTNAME  - root

RDS_PASSWORD - 1234

RDS_PORT  - 3306

RDS_USERNAME  - root

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Github actions, you can add your `.env` variables under repo -> Settings -> Deploy keys.

Comment: I'm using AWS Codepipeline

Comment: Check here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-variables.html